# Is there an uncountable proper sub-field of $\mathbf{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is there an uncountable proper subfield of $\mathbf{R}$?

Comment: See also this [MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27352/a-question-about-fields-of-real-numbers) and [this note](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Ralph_S32939._Butcher,_Wallace_L._Hamilton_and_John_G._Milcetich.pdf).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure. Note that ${\bf R}$ itself is uncountable, so it has an uncountable transcendental basis $\{x_\alpha\mid \alpha\in {\mathfrak c}\}$ over ${\bf Q}$. Then ${\bf Q}(x_\alpha\mid \alpha\in {\mathfrak c})$ is a proper subfield of ${\bf R}$ (because neither of $x_\alpha,-x_\alpha$ has a square root, for example, which is not true in ${\bf R}$).

Alternatively, ${\bf Q}(x_\alpha\mid 0<\alpha\in {\mathfrak c})$ is even more clearly distinct from ${\bf R}$, as it does not contain $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I'm not familiar with abstract-algebra. Can you explain to me what means transcendental basis?

Comment: @Richard: A finite set $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is algebraically independent over a field $K$ if there is no nonzero polynomial $p\in K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ (of $n$ variables with coefficients in $K$) such that $p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$ An infinite set is algebraically independent if all finite subsets are algebraically independent (this is the same as linear independence in many ways). A transcendental basis of a field $L\supseteq K$ is a maximal algebraically independent set.

Comment: @Richard: The cardinality of transcendental basis of $L$ over $K$ (the cardinality is always unique, though the basis certainly isn't; the proof is the same as for linear basis) is called transcendence degree, and denoted by $\operatorname{trdeg}_KL$, and it's not hard to show that $\lvert L\rvert=\lvert K\rvert+\operatorname{trdeg}_KL+\aleph_0$, unless the transcendence degree is zero (then we say that $L$ is an algebraic extension of $K$).

Comment: @Richard: I forgot one thing: If the transcendence degree *is* zero, then $\lvert K\rvert\leq \lvert L\rvert+\aleph_0$, that's why you can conclude that ${\bf R}$ has a basis of cardinality $\mathfrak c$ over ${\bf Q}$.

Comment: \[This is wrong; I am stupid :(\] Simple example: when $x_0 = \sqrt{2}$, the field becomes $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \sqrt{2} \mathbb{Q}) \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: @JiminP: $\sqrt 2$ is not transcendental over $\bf Q$ and $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \sqrt{2} \mathbb{Q}) \cup \{0\}$ is not even closed under addition.

Comment: Oops... I thought too simply... :(

Comment: I wonder, does this construction require the axiom of choice, probably for the existence of the uncountable trancendental basis? Or can we get there by transfinite induction only (still, I am no expert here and I am not sure that transfinite induction up to some ordinal does not need the axiom of choice)?

Comment: It does. Existence of transcendental basis for arbitrary fields should be equivalent to AC. Moreover, a transcendental basis for reals can be easily used to construct a linear basis over rationals.

Answer (score 4):

For an "explicit" answer you might take the field generated by a perfect set of Hausdorff dimension $0$. See e.g. [Measure 0 subfield of R](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/00_incoming/subfield).

Comment: The link is unfortunately  broken. I get a "403 Forbidden", so the linked page seems to be not accessible by everyone.

Comment: Maybe the link can be replaced by this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/27358/108884)?